# Bootstrap html different fonts and style inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make two words with different font size and style be inline?

```
<h2> 
  hello 
  <h1> 
     <b>
       world!
     </b>
  </h1>
 </h2>
```

Desired output:

```
" Hello **world!**  "
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An `<h2>` can't contain a `<h1>`. Why don't you just wrap the `world!` in a span and style it differently?

Comment: Agreed with – j08691, but i'd add that you may be better off working through a tutorial or video to learn the basics of HTML, something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB1O30fR-EE , and then take questions you may have from there and post them. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need CSS code to do this. I have an example here with different size, color and also different style.

First the **HTML**-Code:

```
<h1 style="color: black; font-weight: 100">hello</h1>
<h2 style="color: blue; font-style: italic" >world!</h2>
```

and in CSS you must define `<h1>` and `<h2>` to `display: inline;` if you want both in one line.

**CSS**:

```
h1, h2 {
  display: inline;
}​
```

I hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you learn the basics of HTML before proceeding with CSS, the **span** tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

```html
<div>
  <span style="font-size: 25px; color: red;">Hello</span>
  <span style="font-size: 15px; color: blue;">World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Brayam! it fixes the problem , althrough I wantd an answer of using specifically with H1 H2 etc.

Comment: Oh, yes, I saw that too late, remember that every HTML element has a default display value depending on what type of element it is , take a look at this link to know more about it, however, you can always change the display value of an element with CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp